# Laravel take first 5 foreach

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, foreach

I trying to take out 5 users from DB by points.

BLADE:

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
<li><a href="/players/{!! $user->slug !!}">{!! $user->username !!} {!! $user->ELO_points !!}</li></a>
@endforeach
</div>
```

But i need just first 5 and first 3 with custom text content, example:

- USER1 - CUSTOM CONTENT TEXT
- USER2 - CUSTOM CONTENT TEXT
- USER3 - CUSTOM CONTENT TEXT
- USER4
- USER5

I have been tried with `@if ($loop->first)This is the first iteration.@endif`

But loop take out just first and last one yeah?

Comment: Just use `$loop->index` in your loop, and compare this number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use $loop->index in your loop :

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
   <li><a href="/players/{!! $user->slug !!}">
        {!! $user->username !!} {!! $user->ELO_points !!} 
        {!! $loop->index <=3 ? 'custom content text' : '' !!}
   </a></li>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the take way of doing it. Example
IN CONTROLLER (To make sure you only get the 5, user orderBy to either get the first or the last.)

```
$users = Users::all()->take(5)->get();
```

IN VIEW: (To make sure the 3 first get the custom content text

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
 <li><a href="/players/{{ $user->slug }}">
  {{ $user->username }} {{ $user->ELO_points }}
  {{ $loop->index <=3 ? 'custom content text' : '' }}
 </a></li>
@endforeach
```